# how can I put elements of an array in a checkbox?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks, qcheckbox

I am using react hooks and have a dynamically filled array of values ​​after a backend call. How can I then insert these values ​​(which I don't know a priori) in a checkbox?
I get some properties from another component.
These properties change based on a selection from a table.
I would like to be able to add / remove these properties based on a selection on a checkbox when I open the "Available roles list"

```
const UsersList = (props) => {
  const { loadedRoles } = props;
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState([]);

  const selectHandler = (Event, selected) => {
    loadedRoles(selected.roles);
  };

  const handleChange = (Event) => {
    setChecked({ ...props.roles, [Event.target.name]: Event.target.checked });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <MaterialTable
        title=" Users List"
        data={props.users}
        columns={[
          { title: "User Id", field: "id" },
          { title: "Active", field: "active" },
          { title: "System", field: "system" },
          { title: "Roles", field: "roles" },
        ]}
        options={{
          cellStyle: {
            width: 100,
            minWidth: 100,
            height: 1,
          },
          headerStyle: {
            width: 100,
            minWidth: 100,
          },
        }}
        onRowClick={selectHandler}
      />
      <Card>Current Role: {props.current}</Card>
      <Card>
        <label>Available Roles: {props.roles}</label>
        <Checkbox name={props.roles} onChange={handleChange} />
      </Card>
    </div>
```

Comment: Show us your code, so we can help...

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you mean by "insert values in a checkbox"?

Comment: sorry i'm just using react so i don't know if i mean it ... I edit the question

Answer (score 0):

I can assume that you receive from your backend an array of objects, containing the label, keys, and values for the checkboxes?

```js
[
  { label: 'Checkbox #1', key: 'checkbox1', checked: true },
  { label: 'Checkbox #2', key: 'checkbox2', checked: false },
  { label: 'Checkbox #3', key: 'checkbox3', checked: true },
]
```

You can make the call to the API in a `useEffect`, store the result in a local state via `useState`, then iterate through the values in the rendering:

```js
const [checkboxes, setCheckboxes] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
  fetch('/your/api')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(checkboxes => setCheckboxes(checkboxes))
}, [])

return (
  <ul>
    {checkboxes === null
      ? <li>Loading...</li>
      : checkboxes.map(checkbox => (
          <li key={checkbox.key}>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name={key} defaultChecked={checkbox.checked} />
              {checkbox.label}
            </label>
          </li>
        ))
    }
  </ul>
)
```

The checkboxes here are not controlled (`defaultChecked`). To use controlled checkboxes instead, you’ll need to create another local state and initialize it from the values returned by the backend, and use `checked` & `onChange` props instead.